# How to get acf custom text fields from my WooCommerce product tag terms?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, tags, product, advanced-custom-fields

I am unable to get the acf text field to display in the woocommerce "Product Tag" admin dashboard.

I have tried the following code, along with many other different variations of looping through the products, retrieving their tags and returning the acf text field but no values are appearing in the columns.

The goal is to customize the Product Tag Admin Dashboard to display the acf text field term. I was able to achieve getting these text field terms in a different portion of code when I created a customize side bar that sections tags by categories that are different from the product categories. I tried that same code for the columns but that isn't working either.

[image: The Titles Before The Tags Are The Product Tag ACF Text Field Term]

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_tag_columns', 'tag_category_column_admin', 9999 );
function tag_category_column_admin( $columns ){
  $columns['tag_category'] = 'Tag Category';
  return $columns;
}
add_action('manage_product_tag_custom_column', 'tag_category_column_admin_content', 10, 2);

 function tag_category_column_admin_content($column,$product_id){
  $product_tag_terms = wp_get_post_terms($product_id, 'product_tag');
  foreach($product_tag_terms as $term){
    $category_id = get_field('tag_category' , $term, true);
    return $category_id;
  }
  if($column == 'tag_category'){
    echo $category_id;
 }
}
```

[image: Here is the admin dashboard. As you can see, it's displaying the column title but it's not generating any of the terms in the table cells within the]

I have looked everywhere and cannot seem to find a solution to my problem. Please help!

Comment: Have you tried the "Admin Columns" plugin? Even if the free version don't officially support ACF fields, I believe you can get them through "custom field" (https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/codepress-admin-columns/)

Comment: You're using the hook param wrong, read the param information on this [documentation page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_this-screen-taxonomy_custom_column/) and `manage_product_tags_custom_column` should be `manage_product_tag_custom_column` you're using extra `s`

Comment: @VijayHardaha after making the changes it worked! thank you!!